# how to get max usage of mem and cpu usage of pod on kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes

I defined my deployment resources

```
    resources:
      limits:
        cpu: 900m
        memory: 2500Mi
```

now on http://localhost:8001/api [image]

how can I get the **max** usage of memory and cpu (in order to handle and define usages and resources well)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are running on GKE

for now day, the kubernetes console has advanced and you can see all statistics on the console ui

go to https://console.cloud.google.com/kubernetes/list

under `workloads` choose the deployment

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Usually, you will need to implement some monitoring solution for your K8s cluster to store historical metrics.

If your Kubernetes deployment runs on GKE, you can use [Stackdriver](https://cloudplatform.googleblog.com/2015/12/monitoring-Container-Engine-with-Google-Cloud-Monitoring.html)
for that and if you have opted for [Stackdriver Premium](https://cloud.google.com/stackdriver/pricing), you will see your historical metrics there. If it's your own Kubernetes deployment, [Prometheus/Grafana](https://prometheus.io/) is a popular choice

Answer (score 1):

By default the pods run with unbounded CPU and memory limits. This means that any pod in the system will be able to consume as much CPU and memory as is on the node that executes the pod.

Reference: 
https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/cpu-memory-limit/

Answer (score 1):

Some tools like `kubectl top` can only get the resource usage of your pod in current time. You need a monitor service.

[kube-state-metrics](https://github.com/kubernetes/kube-state-metrics)  -> [prometheus](https://prometheus.io/) ->  [grafana-kubernetes-app](https://github.com/grafana/kubernetes-app) is a popular solution to monitor metrics of self deployed k8s cluster.

`kube-state-metrics` can generates metrics about the state of k8s objects, such as node, pod, deployment.

> you just need to trace metrics `kube_pod_container_resource_requests_cpu_cores` and `kube_pod_container_resource_requests_memory_bytes` as the [document](https://github.com/kubernetes/kube-state-metrics/blob/master/Documentation/pod-metrics.md) specified.

`peometheus` should collect metrics from `kube-state-metrics` every few seconds and generate time series data.

`grafana-kubernetes-app` charts them easily. You can find the maximum cpu usage of a given pod then.

Answer (score 1):

A little late to the party, but I created Kube Eagle for exactly this purpose: https://github.com/google-cloud-tools/kube-eagle

[image: Kube Eagle dashboard]