# How to retrieve pod memory and cpu usage from Kubernetes using Java Api

Tags: kubernetes

Is there a Java API to retrieve the CPU and Memory usage of the pod? I am not looking for a complete monitoring solution like using Grafana or Prometheus or not using the kubectl top pod, but wanted to retrieve the current usage using Java API. Any example or reference documentation on how to do will be of great help.

Client libraries

https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/using-api/client-libraries/

Examples - https://github.com/kubernetes-client/java#installation

Similar questions:

[how to get max usage of mem and cpu usage of pod on kubernetes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44352621/how-to-get-max-usage-of-mem-and-cpu-usage-of-pod-on-kubernetes)

[kubernetes Pod CPU usage in % from metric server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60144569/kubernetes-pod-cpu-usage-in-from-metric-server)

Thanks.

Comment: I found similar question using go client https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52763291/get-current-resource-usage-of-a-pod-in-kubernetes-with-go-client

Answer (score 1):

You can install the [Metrics Server](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/metrics-server) and then fetch the resource usage of Pods with direct HTTP requests to the [Resource Metrics API](https://github.com/kubernetes/community/blob/master/contributors/design-proposals/instrumentation/resource-metrics-api.md#endpoints) through the API server:

```
GET /apis/metrics/v1alpha1/namespaces/{namespace}/pods/{pod}
```

The Resource Metrics API does not seem to be included in the official [Java client library](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/java/). So, you probably have to make the API requests manually.

Comment: thanks for the reply. Looks like that is the only option. But I have seen some classes in the API but not clear on how to retrieve the current values V2beta1ResourceMetricStatus https://javadoc.io/static/io.kubernetes/client-java-api/3.0.0/io/kubernetes/client/models/V2beta1ResourceMetricStatus.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Fabric8 java client for Kubernates.

Refer this link for an example implementation:

https://github.com/rohanKanojia/kubernetes-client/commit/d6453e0b6a424c89d0f9e237ab818a0f456ec11f#diff-d8a58a09a3dece4f92fd5fefd1927e08

```
try (KubernetesClient client = new DefaultKubernetesClient()) {
      NodeMetricsList nodeMetricList = client.top().nodes().metrics();

      log("name CPU(cores) CPU(%) Memory(Bytes) Memory(%)");
      for (NodeMetrics nodeMetrics : nodeMetricList.getItems()) {
        log(nodeMetrics.toString());
        log(nodeMetrics.getUsage().toString());
        log(nodeMetrics.getMetadata().getName() +
          " " + nodeMetrics.getUsage().get("cpu") +
          " " + nodeMetrics.getUsage().get("memory"));
      }

    } catch (KubernetesClientException e) {
      logger.error(e.getMessage(), e);
```

For pods,

```
PodMetricsList podMetricList = client.top().pods().metrics();
            for(PodMetrics metrics: podMetricList.getItems())
            {
                for(ContainerMetrics containerMetric : metrics.getContainers())
                {
                    Quantity quantity = containerMetric.getUsage().get("cpu");
                    String amount = quantity.getAmount();
                }
            }
```

Also, pasting this link for reference:

https://developers.redhat.com/blog/2020/05/20/getting-started-with-the-fabric8-kubernetes-java-client/